# SQL QUERY For totals from two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a QUERY to return the totals from each car. Each key here is a purchase, and these purchases can have the Car ID in either the "Header" table or the "Lines" Table, because a purchase can be either for just one car, or for many cars. Is it possible to get something like the Result table as shown below?

Header:

```
╔═════╦════════╦═══════╗
║ Key ║ Total  ║  Car  ║
╠═════╬════════╬═══════╣
║   1 ║ 100.00 ║ Car 1 ║
║   2 ║ 350.00 ║       ║
║   3 ║ 230.24 ║ Car 1 ║
║   4 ║ 121.01 ║ Car 2 ║
║   5 ║ 110.00 ║       ║
╚═════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

Lines:

```
╔═════╦══════╦═══════════╦═══════╗
║ Key ║ Line ║ LineTotal ║  Car  ║
╠═════╬══════╬═══════════╬═══════╣
║   1 ║    0 ║ 100.00    ║       ║
║   2 ║    0 ║ 350.00    ║ Car 2 ║
║   3 ║    0 ║ 30.24     ║ Car 1 ║
║   3 ║    1 ║ 200.00    ║ Car 1 ║
║   4 ║    0 ║ 121.01    ║       ║
║   5 ║    0 ║ 10.00     ║ Car 1 ║
║   5 ║    1 ║ 100.00    ║ Car 2 ║
╚═════╩══════╩═══════════╩═══════╝
```

Result:

```
╔═══════╦════════╦═════╗
║  Car  ║ Value  ║ Key ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════╣
║ Car 1 ║ 100.00 ║   1 ║
║ Car 1 ║ 230.24 ║   3 ║
║ Car 1 ║ 10.00  ║   5 ║
║ Car 2 ║ 350.00 ║   2 ║
║ Car 2 ║ 121.01 ║   4 ║
║ Car 2 ║ 100.00 ║   5 ║
╚═══════╩════════╩═════╝
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT A.Car, SUM(A.Total), A.Key
FROM HEADER A
GROUP BY A.Car,A.Key

UNION

SELECT B.Car, SUM(B.LineTotal), B.Key
FROM LINES B
GROUP BY B.Car,B.Key
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Comment: James or Martin--so hard to tell

Comment: @scsimon I bet its hard! A fan of him!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(l.Car,h.Car) as Car
    ,SUM(l.LineTotal) AS Value
    ,l.[Key]
FROM
    Lines l
    INNER JOIN Header h
    ON l.[Key] = h.[Key]
GROUP BY
    ISNULL(l.Car,h.Car)
    ,l.[Key]
ORDER BY
    ISNULL(l.Car,h.Car)
    ,l.[Key]
```

If the blanks are actually empty strings and not NULL then you would just have to change up slightly to something like this:

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(NULLIF(l.Car,''),h.Car) as Car
    ,SUM(l.LineTotal) AS Value
    ,l.[Key]
FROM
    @Lines l
    INNER JOIN @Header h
    ON l.[Key] = h.[Key]
GROUP BY
    ISNULL(NULLIF(l.Car,''),h.Car)
    ,l.[Key]
ORDER BY
    ISNULL(NULLIF(l.Car,''),h.Car)
    ,l.[Key]
```

Comment: You are taking only sum of `Lines.Value` so in this case `Total` from `Header` will be excluded. So you will get data only from `Lines` but no data from `Header`

Comment: @AVKNaidu the Total From Header is the SUM(Lines.LineTotal) when the car is known at header level.  So when you SUM(Lines.LineTotal) it will still total correctly

Comment: That is correct. But if you see Table `Header` There is a Key 1 with Value 100, So when you Sum(Lines.LineTotal) you are accounting for Key 3 and 5 but not 1. Which should also be part of result set.

Comment: @AVKNaidu becuse I am using ISNULL() which is COALESCE and joining on the KEY the 100 will still be apart of the result set.

Comment: @AVKNaidu http://rextester.com/XBTKX95647, the difference is I am treading the blanks as NULL not empty string that is usually the most common meaning when omitted in questions. if they are in fact empty strings that is easy enough too just switch to a case statement to test but this method works.

Comment: Ah!!. I see the difference now. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Nah man. I usually downvote only if there is no clarification from OP about their answer. It must be someone else. Upvoted now after you updated your answer. Cheers!!

Comment: @AVKNaidu cool, funny I guess we should have actually commented rather than assuming because it does mean that the accepted answer would be wrong as the NULL and or Empty string isn't actually filtered out for CAR, the way you do it would work though so +1 for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Key in `Header` is always Unique and Sum of Keys is the final output from `Lines`, Below is how you can do this.

```
;with cte (Car,Value,[Key]) as
(
    select Car,Total,[Key] from Header
    union
    select Car,sum(LineTotal),[Key] from Lines group by [Key],Car
)
select Car,Value,[Key] from cte where isnull(car,'')!='' order by Car,[Key]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me a simple join aggregrate and group by should work. along with a coalesce to choose the correct value for car.

1. First we join Header to lines on Key.
2. Next we take the first non-null value to get a value for car starting in line then going to header.
3. We then sum the values in the lines as for a given key and car there may be multiple lines.
4. We group by the value for the car and l.key (the non-aggregrates in the select)
5. Finally we order by the car value then the key in the default (Asc) order.

Coalesce returns the first non-null value in a series of values and can early exit once a value is found. It requires all values to be of the same datatype.

.

```
SELECT Coalesce(L.car, H.car) as Car
     , sum(L.value) as value
     , L.Key
FROM Header H
INNER JOIN Lines L
 on H.Key = L.Key
GROUP BY Coalesce(L.car, H.car), L.Key
ORDER BY Coalesce(L.car, H.car), L.Key
```

Comment: You are taking only sum of `Lines.Value` so in this case `Total` from `Header` will be excluded. So you will get data only from `Lines` but no data from `Header`

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

```
select distinct * from
(select
    c.car,
    sum(c.value) as Total,
    c.[key]
from 
(select 
    h.Car as car, h.Total as value, h.[key] as [key]
from  header as h where car <> '') 
as c
group by c.car, c.[key]
union all
select
    c.car,
    sum(c.value) as Total,
    c.[key]
from 
(
select 
    l.Car as car, l.LineTotal as value, l.[key] as [key]
from  lines as l where car <> '') 
as c
group by c.car, c.[key])
as c
order by c.car, c.[key]
```

But you could improve your tables, put better relationships